# how to change drive for Partitioned tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a large table should have been partitioned in different derives but all of them in one drive (**D:\sql\import2006.ndf**), (**D:\sql\import2007.ndf**).how can i move them in to their own drives like data2006,data2007 etc without loosing data.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the terminology incorrectly and is not clear what you want to achieve. A table has one or more partitions. Each partition resides in a filegroup. A filegroup hase one or more files. A file is stored on a logical drive. A logical drive can be backed by one or more physical drives.

What is that you want to change?

- Did you load data in the wrong partition of the table?
- Did you load the data in an unpartitioned table and now you need it to be partitioned? (This is really the same question as the first one)
- Did you placed the partition in the wrong filegroup?
- Did you place one or more filegroup files on the wrong logical drive?
- Did you place a logical drive on the wrong physical drive?

Each problem has a different solution.

Comment: all filegroup files are in one partition which is  d:sql\data2006 i m trying to put them in to different partitions such as e:sql\data2007,f:\sql\data2008  etc and logical drives.like placing partition wrong drive and wrong file group thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about 'partition' as in table partitions or 'partition' as in disk partitions?

Comment: To move around the files that compose a database, use the [KB224071](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071) as @podiluska linked

Answer (score 1):

You can detach the database, move the files, then reattach

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071